# Mixing one and two column floats on a page

Tags: graphics, floats

I am using the `ieeetran` document class, which uses a two-column layout.
Using `figure` and `figure*` I try to have one- and two-column figures on the same page, but for some reason, LaTeX refuses to do this.

The following MWE shows my problem:

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}                          % GRAPHICS: Advanced graphics loading
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}                % DEVELOPMENT: Provide blind text like lipsum but better

\begin{document}
\title{Foobar}
\author{Mox}

% The paper headers
\markboth{Foo}{Bar}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    This is an MWE for one and two column figures.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    figure, figure*
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{I}{n} this paper I would really like to have one-column and two-column graphics on the same page.
\blindtext % Blindtext calls are separated to yield paragraphs for sure

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

% Top of right column on second page...
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A graphic using \emph{figure}.}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

% This should be on the bottom of the second page...
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{A graphic using \emph{figure*}.}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]
[image: page 3]
[image: page 4]

Is there a simple way to have both images on the same page?
Please do not propose complete manual placement of the graphics, that would be beside the point for me. I want the graphics to float to where I want them.

Comment: figure* always appears at the earliest on the page after it appears in the source, so you need to move it earlier in the document. also by default bottom floats are not supported by latex two column floats

Comment: both image on the same page you ca obtain with use of the package `stfloats` which enable appearing of image on the bottom of the same page (if there is sufficient space). in your case the second image is to big that it can be fit on the same page with the first image.

Comment: Why would the second image be too big? There should still be nearly half a textheight between them if the image was moved to the second page.
Is there a way to override what is considered `enough' space?